# set up Windows 10 PC as internet gateway for a Linux PC on local LAN to access internet

Tags: networking, windows-10, lan, network-adapter, gateway

I have a Windows 10 PC with two NICs that I want to use as a gateway between a small LAN which is using 192.168.0.x IPv4 addressing and the internet.

What I have set up is the Windows 10 PC with two NICs. One NIC has an Ethernet cable running from the NIC to the wall giving the PC access to the university LAN and the internet. The second NIC has an Ethernet cable running to a small 24 port network switch to which other PCs are cabled including a Dell tower which is running Ubuntu Linux.

On the Windows 10 PC the NIC connected to the university LAN has its Properties set up use DHCP and DNS and everything works fine. I am able to access the university LAN and the internet. I can read web pages in a browser and I can ping google.com as well as other PCs on the university LAN that I have in my lab.

On the Windows 10 PC with the second NIC connected to the network switch I have a static IP of 192.168.0.97.

On the Dell Linux box I have set up the NIC with a static IP of 192.168.0.151.

I am able to ping the Windows 10 PC using address 192.168.0.97 from the Linux box. I am able to ping the Linux box using address 192.168.0.151 from the Windows 10 PC.

However I am unable to ping internet sites such as google.com nor am I able to ping other PCs on the university LAN that I have in my lab from the Linux box. When I try to use a browser on the Linux box to access websites, the browser times out and there is no content from the site.

So it appears that there is something that I need to do to inform the Windows 10 PC that it needs to bridge between the NIC attached to the 192.168.0.x LAN and the other NIC attached to the university LAN and the internet.

I had had this working correctly with a Windows XP PC acting as the gateway a while back but I am unable to figure out how to set this up under Windows 10. The Network UI for Windows 10 is a bit confusing and seems to lack the functionality to do this.

How do I set up a Windows 10 Enterprise PC with two NICs as a gateway between a 192.168.0.x LAN on one NIC and the university LAN and internet on the second NIC?

Comment: this may be related https://superuser.com/questions/590410/how-to-route-traffic-to-one-specific-nic-when-two-are-installed

Comment: There are discussions about bridging between the two NICs. Also the 192.168.0.x network NIC should not have a gateway IP address specified.